# Path returns error when using DJS-Commander

Tags: node.js, path, discord.js

I have this in my index.js file:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { CommandHandler } = require('djs-commander');
const path = require('path');
const chalk = require('chalk');

require('dotenv').config();
const { token } = process.env;

const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds]
})

new CommandHandler({
    client: client,
    commandsPath: path.join(__dirname, 'commands'),
    testServer: '1083027628329545758'
})

client.on('ready', () => console.log(chalk.green(`[CLIENT]`) + ` ${client.user.tag} started.`))

client.login(token)
```

But, when using path with DJS-Commander I get this error:

```
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file and data are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at throwIfUnsupportedURLScheme (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1059:11)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1135:3)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:525:22)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1186:29)
    at importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:429:21)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/vm:106:46) {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME'
}
```

I already updated/reinstalled node.js and nothing seems to work.
I also searched here for some solutions, but the only thing I could find was to update my Node.js, thing that I already did.